# How I fix my sdk folder error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Display that error while installing

[error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW6WX.png)

Welcome , I admit that I'm new in Android Studio , Firstly i remove my sdk folder and try to re install android studio. but second time sdk folder files not download well. how i fix that error

Answer (score 0):

Update the android sdk and then try to re-install